# Are switchbacks travelling Alfven waves?

Tags: waves, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, solar-wind

My question is are the so-called Switchbacks observed in the solar wind traveling Alfven waves? If not what are the differences between them?

Comment: If you go with the simplest/broadest definition of an Alfven wave, then the answer is yes.  Namely, they are a variation in the magnetic field that moves through space.  However, you will quickly find this needs refinement when you realize the solar wind can be "clumpy" so you don't start including non-propagating density variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of March 9, 2021 switchbacks seem to still be an unsolved mystery. Alfven waves look like one possible explanation. Nasa's website has an article with a figure showing 5 theories that might explain switchbacks: https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2021/switchbacks-science-explaining-parker-solar-probe-s-magnetic-puzzle

The figure says a thousand words and makes pretty clear what the differences are in the different explanations. Explanation number 3 "expanding plasma ripples" seems to start with Alfven waves. However, the other theories look pretty plausible to me as well.

Edit: Here is Squire et al's paper about the Alfven wave explanation: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/ab74e1